# Receiving and deleting messages from sqs using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, message, boto3, amazon-sqs

I am trying to receive and delete that message one by one. This is my code for your reference.

```
def receive_delete(url , attr_names):
    global sqs
    response = sqs.receive_message(QueueUrl=url,
                               AttributeNames=attr_names,
                               MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
                               MessageAttributeNames=['All'])

    delete_msgs = []

    for messages in response['Messages']:

        delete_msgs.append({'Id':messages['MessageId'],
            'ReceiptHandle': messages['ReceiptHandle']})

        while len(delete_msgs) > 0:
            sqs.delete_message(QueueUrl=url , ReceiptHandle=['ReceiptHandle'])
```

and then i am calling that function like this ...

```
x = receive_delete("https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/266638361021/tony.fifo", attr)
```

Problem is , when i run this method , it gets stuck and when i check on amazon sqs dashboard , it shows only one message is deleted.

How can i delete message one by one after receiving it ?

Comment: According to boto3 documentation,  `sqs.delete_message`  parameter `ReceiptHandle` only accept string.  For batch delete, use `delete_message_batch`, but again, you need to construct individual "entries"  for each message.

Comment: ok , thanks.This would be helpful.

Comment: You seem to have an infinite loop because delete_msgs is never updated: `while len(delete_msgs) > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Well this worked for me.
I read a message (one) from a FIFO queue and process in the middle then delete using the `receiptHandle`. This is the code -

```
import boto3

queue = "your_queue_url"

def process_message():
    sqs_client = boto3.client("sqs")
    response = sqs_client.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=queue,
        MaxNumberOfMessages=1,
        WaitTimeSeconds=15,
    )
    # print(response)
    # print(response)

    print(f"Number of messages received: {len(response.get('Messages', []))}")

    message = response.get("Messages", [])[0]
    # print(message)
    message_body = message["Body"]
    receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']
    print(f"Message body: {message_body}")
    print(f"Receipt Handle: {receipt_handle}")

    # trying to delete the message
    dlt_response = sqs_client.delete_message(
        QueueUrl=queue,
        ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
        )

    print("Deleted? ", message_body)
    print(dlt_response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'])

process_message()
```

Hope this helps.